# Why can't a pointer be automatically converted into a unique_ptr when returning it?

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, smart-pointers, explicit

Consider the following program:

```
#include <memory>

std::unique_ptr<int> get_it() {
    auto p = new int;
    return p;
}

int main() {
    auto up ( get_it() );
    return 0;
}
```

This fails to compile with the following error:

```
a.cpp:5:9: error: could not convert ‘p’ from ‘int*’ to ‘std::unique_ptr<int>’
  return p;
         ^
```

Why isn't there an automatic conversion from a raw pointer to a unique one here? And what should I be doing instead?

Motivation: I understand it's supposed to be good practice to use smart pointers for ownership to be clear; I'm getting a pointer (which I own) from somewhere, as an `int*` in this case, and I (think I) want it in a `unique_ptr`.

---

If you're considering commenting or adding your own answer, please address [Herbert Sutter's arguments for this to be possible in proposal N4029](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4029.pdf).

Comment: Because then things like `int x; return &x;` would compile.

Comment: @KerrekSB: I can also do `int *p = nullptr; *p = 123;` and that will compile. Anyway, not to be too argumentative - I'll ask - what should I do, then?

Comment: You make one from your pointer, e.g. `std::unique_ptr<int>(p)`.

Comment: @VincentSavard:  But isn't that exactly what I'm doing by returning p as an `std::unique_ptr<int>`?

Comment: No, you're returning `p`, which is of type `int*`, not `std::unique_ptr<int>`. Maybe you do not understand what `auto` does.

Comment: `return std::make_unique<int>();` [`std::make_unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique)

Comment: @VincentSavard: The return type is `std::unique_ptr<int>`, I can only return that. I mean, the int* is supposed to be cast. Just like if I returned 3.5 in a function returning int.

Comment: @Joe: Assume you can't avoid p. Somehow an `int* p` gets created and set (in a magical way which I've left out of the MWE).

Comment: And that's why the compiler doesn't compile this code. Is your question "Why isn't `p` implicitly cast to `std::unique_ptr`?"

Comment: @VincentSavard: If that were the case, I should not be able to compile `int foo() { return 3.5; }` and need to do `int foo() { return (int)3.5;}` - but I don't need that.

Comment: Because implicit conversion from `double` to `int` is defined. You're mixing different concepts.

Comment: @einpoklum: Still, that's a different level of wrong. Your `p` is not dereferenceable, which is your fault. My `&x` is a perfectly valid int pointer.

Comment: @cat: [cannot reproduce](https://ideone.com/F8XqFv)

Comment: @cat: also [cannot reproduce with GCC 5.2](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/oEuJnSB1ciXX6NtA).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The answer is two-fold. All the other answers, including a OP's self-answer, addressed only one half of it.

The pointer cannot be automatically converted because:

- `unique_ptr`'s [constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr) from a pointer is declared `explicit`, thus considered by the compiler only in explicit contexts. This is done so to prevent accidental dangerous conversions, where a `unique_ptr` can hijack a pointer and delete it without programmer's knowledge. In general, not only for `unique_ptr`, it is considered a good practice to declare all single-argument constructors as `explicit` to prevent accidental conversions.
- return statement is considered by the standard an implicit context, and thus the explicit constructor is not applicable. There was an ongoing discussion if this decision is right, reflected in [EWG issue 114](https://cplusplus.github.io/EWG/ewg-closed.html#114), including links to several proposals: two versions of proposals to make `return` explicit by Herb Sutter ([N4029](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2014/n4029.pdf), [N4074](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2014/n4074.pdf)), and two "responses", arguing not to do so: [N4094](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2014/n4094.html) by Howard Hinnant and Ville Voutilainen and [N4131](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2014/n4131.html) by Filip Roséen. After several discussions and polls the issue was closed as NAD - not a defect.

Currently, there are several workarounds:

```
return std::unique_ptr<int>{p};
```

or

```
return std::unique_ptr<int>(p);
```

In c++14, you can use auto-deduction of function return type as well:

```
auto get_it() {
    auto p = new int;
    return std::unique_ptr<int>(p);
}
```

Update: added a link to committee issue for the second point.

Comment: Thank you for bringing Mr. Sutter's proposal and the EWG discussion to my attention, that is most illuminating (and I have to also say - standing in contrast to some people's dismissive attitude).

Comment: "it is considered a good practice to declare all single-argument constructors as explicit to prevent accidental conversions" --- who considers this a good practice? The standard library itself doesn't follow this rule. For example, std::shared_ptr<T> is implicitly constructible from std::unique_ptr<T>.

Answer (score 9):

Because implicit construction of `unique_ptr` from naked pointer would be very error-prone.

Just construct it explicitly:

```
std::unique_ptr<int> get_it() {
        auto p = new int;
        return std::unique_ptr<int>(p);
}
```

Comment: I can't say I understand how it would be error prone in a function returning a `unique_ptr`. Can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: E.g. `foo(unique_ptr<int> p) {}` in such case would be able to steal a passed naked pointer, and destroy the object.

Comment: Your example does not involve a function returning a unique_ptr, so - I don't follow...

Comment: Explicitness of an object construction is defined by a constructor definition. So, you can't do that implicitly when return the object, but explicitly in other cases.

Comment: So, you're saying this is related to the `explicit` keyword?

Comment: Yes. `unique_ptr` constructor from naked pointer is defined as explicit.

Comment: This answers OP's question well - raw pointers cannot be implicitly converted to smart pointers.

Answer (score 5):

Because `std::unique_ptr` takes ownership of the pointer, and you definitely don't want to get your raw pointer `delete`d accidentally.

If that would be possible, then:

```
void give_me_pointer(std::unique_ptr<int>) { /* whatever */ }

int main() {
    int *my_int = new int;
    give_me_pointer(my_int);
    // my_int is dangling pointer
}
```

Comment: That's not the reason IMO. `get_it` returns a unique pointer, it is obvious returning a pointer from means transferring ownership.

Comment: Good point, but I don't think C++ is smart enough to distinguish between this case and case in the question. So, both are allowed, or both are forbidden.

Comment: @einpoklum : This _is_ indeed the reason.

Answer (score 4):

Because the conversion, or casting, requires an appropriate cast operator (on the source type) or constructor (on the target type). In this case it [must be](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr) the following constructor of `unique_ptr`:

```
explicit unique_ptr( pointer p );
```

Which has the [explicit keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/q/121162/1593077). your `get_it()` attempts implicit conversion, which `explicit` prevents. Instead, you have to construct the `unique_ptr` explicitly, as suggested by [@Stas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34882576/1593077) and @VincentSavard :

```
std::unique_ptr<int> get_it() {
        auto p = new int;
        return std::unique_ptr<int>(p);
}
```

or even, if we want to only say `unique_ptr` once...

```
auto get_it() {
        auto p = new int;
        return std::unique_ptr<int>(p);
}
```

Comment: Forgive me if this is a silly question, but why not just `make_unique`?

Comment: @erip: Because this is an MWE. Actually we have `auto p = do_stuff_which_returns_a_raw_pointer()`

Comment: Right, but you could simply do `auto get_it() { auto p = new int; return std::make_unique<int>(p); }`, could you not? I would think that forwarding would be preferred to explicit ctor call.

Comment: @erip: In this example, yes. But, you know, I could just `int main() { return 0;}` since I don't do anything with `p`...

Comment: I think you're missing my point. I've edited my comment to be more reflective of my intent.

Comment: @erip That's exactly what the bottom of my answer suggests.

Comment: Errr... No. There's a difference between constructing and forwarding an object.

Comment: Also, why are you referring to yourself as OP? :) Typically self-answers should add something that other answers _haven't_. I think your answer is covered by @Stas 's answer.

Comment: @erip: I think it would be more confusing if I wrote "oh, I can do this instead of that". Anyway, no, my answer is not covered by what Stas wrote; and I don't agree with part of his answer.

Comment: Maybe not, but definitely covered the comments which is part of @Stas 's answer.

Comment: @erip: (shrugs) you're kind of splitting hairs here. I wrote up another answer because I want to express the way I understood it. This won't be the accepted answer anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Because it is dangerous.

Use `std::make_unique()` from C++14:

```
std::unique_ptr<int> get_it()
{
    auto p = std::make_unique<int>();
    return p;
}
```