# Is there a transparent way of using unique_ptr in std containers?

Tags: c++, c++17, unique-ptr, stdmap

Is there a transparent way of using `std::unique_ptr` in  containers?

```
#include <iostream>                                                                                                                         
#include <memory>                                                                                                                           
#include <map>                                                                                                                              

struct method {                                                                                                                             
    virtual ~method() { std::cout << "f\n"; };                                                                                              
};                                                                                                                                          
typedef std::unique_ptr<method> MPTR;                                                                                                       

std::map<int, MPTR> tbl;                                                                                                                    

void insert(int id, method *m) {                                                                                                            
    tbl.insert({id,std::unique_ptr<method>(m)});                                                                                            
};                                                                                                                                          

void set(int id, method *m) {                                                                                                               
    tbl[id] = std::unique_ptr<method>(m);                                                                                                   
};                                                                                                                                          

int main(int argc, char **argv) {                                                                                                           

    insert(1,new method());                                                                                                                 
    set(1,new method());                                                                                                                    
    return 0;                                                                                                                               
}
```

I'd like to use `tbl.insert({id,m});` and `tbl[id] = m;` etc. instead of having to wrap/unwrap for each access.

- Are there implementations of std containers for unique_ptr? In particular `std::map`.
- How would a transparent interface be implemented?

Comment: I don't understand your question: what are you trying to do with the map and the wrapping?

Comment: @JVApen : I want a map that destroys its items at the end/when overwriting. I’m using the raw pointer outside of the code. I want to get rid of the noise generated by having to wrap/unwrap when saving and also accessing.

Comment: Why would you want to prefer raw pointers over the unique one?

Comment: @JVApen: dont need unique pointers ouside of the map code. Lifecycle is managed  in the map only. It would be ideal if c++ standard had a quailifier called 'unique' for pointers and C++ could do it transparently..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you pass a raw pointer into a function, it is generally unknown who is expected to keep ownership of the pointed-to object when the function exits - the caller or the callee.  There is nothing in the language to specify or enforce that.

So, it is generally good practice to pass in a raw pointer only when the callee reads or modifies the object but the caller is expected to maintain ownership.

In your example, that is not the case.  You want your functions to take ownership of the allocated `method` objects.  So, you should change your functions to pass in `std::unique_ptr<method>` objects by value, instead of passing raw `method*` pointers.  That makes it very explicit that ownership is expected to pass from the caller to the callee, eg:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <map>

struct method {
    virtual ~method() { std::cout << "f\n"; };
};
typedef std::unique_ptr<method> MPTR;

std::map<int, MPTR> tbl;

void insert(int id, MPTR m) {
    tbl.insert(std::make_pair(id, std::move(m)));
};

void set(int id, MPTR m) {
    tbl[id] = std::move(m);
};

int main()
{
    insert(1, MPTR(new method)); // or insert(1, std:::make_unique<method>()) in C++14 and later
    set(1, MPTR(new method)); // or set(1, std:::make_unique<method>()) in C++14 and later
    return 0;                                                                                                                               
}
```

[Live demo](https://ideone.com/ZaF7K4)

Answer (score 10):

Generally, we don't want to implicitly create `std::unique_ptr` because [that can be dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34882140/why-cant-a-pointer-be-automatically-converted-into-a-unique-ptr-when-returning/34886264).

In this sample, I'd recommend starting out with a `unique_ptr` rather than a bare `new`.  This [makes sure the entire lifetime is tracked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37514509/advantages-of-using-stdmake-unique-over-new-operator).

```
#include <memory>
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    auto m = std::make_unique<method>();
    insert(1, std::move(m));
}
```

within `insert` you can also use `std::move` to transfer ownership to the collection.

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like to use `tbl.insert({id,m});` and `tbl[id] = m;` instead of having to wrap/unwrap for each access.

Why? This hides information from the reader. It is important to know whether something is dynamically allocated or not.

---

> Are there implementations of std containers for unique_ptr? In particular `std::map`.

Not in the Standard Library.

---

> How would a transparent interface be implemented?

Store a normal container inside your wrapper, provide forwarding functions that create `unique_ptr` where required. Iterators could unwrap automatically. E.g.

```
template <typename T>
class unique_ptr_vector
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>> _data;

public:
    template <typename... Ts>
    void emplace_back(Ts&&... xs)
    {
        _data.emplace_back(std::make_unique<T>(std::forward<Ts>(xs)...));
    }
};
```

Comment: It seems that I need to write a derivate of ```std::map``` myself then.