# What does the asterix '*' after a template type mean?

Tags: c++, templates

I came template code that uses `*` after a template type:

```
  ...
  template <typename _Up, typename _Ep, typename = void>
  struct _Ptr
  {
      using type = _Up*; 
  };
  ...
```

another usage I saw

```
   ...
   template <typename T, typename \
   std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value,T>::type* = nullptr>
   ...
```

Where is this construct described?

Comment: Note that `_Up`, `_Ep` and `_Ptr` are reserved identifiers, so unless you came across that in an implementation of the standard library, the usage of the identifiers would have undefined behaviour.

Comment: Looks like you are diving into the Standard Library implementation. Before you use this code as a Shining Example to be imitated, note that only the Standard Library implementation [is allowed to use underscores  in particular ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier).

Comment: @eerorika: Didnt know that. I'm just browsing the unique_pointer code in /usr/include/c++/*.

Comment: @KonradEisele well, that would explain why they use identifiers that are reserved for that very purpose. Just remember not to imitate their usage of underscores.

Comment: @KonradEisele I would sincerely discourage you from learning C++ by looking at STL implementation.

Comment: @SergeyA : There is a  reason though: I got irritated of the noise that is generated when using a std::unique_ptr with a std::map, which I asked here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54223750/is-there-a-transparent-way-of-using-unique-ptr-in-std-containers . So I tried to figure out  weather I can derive from  std::unique_ptr that would allow me to skip the wrap/unwrap.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Means the same thing that it would mean for any type - it is a pointer to a `type` defined inside `std::enable_if` specialized for true condition, which is by default `void` - yielding all familiar `void*`.

On a completely different (and possibly ill-advised) note this is not the first time I see a question from you which touches on rather complicated topic (SFINAE is one), which demonstrates that some basic fundamentals are not there yet. I sincerely recommend reading a good C++ book - you can find curated list here: [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: Also, as an aside, the standard is currently undecided on whether that is well-formed, because `void*` is not a pointer to class type.

Comment: @AndyG that is something I am not familiar with! Do you have some further reading advice?

Comment: Thanks for the list to the list of books. Yes, I' still learning... "Effective Modern C++"  I have actually.

Comment: @AndyG, thanks for the link. Wasn't aware of this. But looks like this is how it is done anywhere despite this fact :D

Comment: @SergeyA: Indeed it does. I used this pattern for a long time before discovering this fact. It's safe to use `typename std::enable_if<condition, int>::type = 0`

Comment: @AndyG I've also switched and use `typename std::enable_if<condition, bool>::type = true`/`std::enable_if_t<condition, bool> = true`

Comment: @NathanOliver We spoke about it a couple of days back, and I immediately remembered this conversation. However, you didn't tell me why, just said it feels more descriptive to you :)